When getting styles from an Excel template, only the first column's style is retrieved if multiple columns have styles applied
Problem Description
I have two files: input.csv containing data and template.xlsx containing styles. I'm trying to create output.xlsx using these files.
Issue
If the cells in template.xlsx have styles directly applied to them, there is no problem. However, if the cells are empty and only the column has styles applied, the styles are not correctly transferred. Specifically, when multiple columns have styles applied, only the style from the first column is carried over.
Background
I have previously asked a similar question(If python input a value in an empty cell, can I get the style applied to that row or col?) and, based on the answers, created a function called apply_style_if_empty. This function allows me to get the style from a column when the cell is empty. However, it only works for the first column if multiple columns have styles.
Example
I created an empty template file and applied colors to multiple columns.

When I use the provided code to copy values, only the first column (A) retains the color, and the other columns lose their styles.

Question
Is there a way to ensure that the styles from all columns are correctly transferred?
import openpyxl
import csv
import sys
import copy

def apply_style_if_empty(worksheet, cell):
    column = cell.column_letter
    row = cell.row
    column_properties = worksheet.column_dimensions.get(column, None)
    row_properties = worksheet.row_dimensions.get(row, None)

    # Check if the cell is empty
    if cell.value is None:
        # Apply style from column_dimensions if available
        if column_properties:
            if column_properties.fill:
                cell.fill = copy.copy(column_properties.fill)
            if column_properties.font:
                cell.font = copy.copy(column_properties.font)
            if column_properties.alignment:
                cell.alignment = copy.copy(column_properties.alignment)
            if column_properties.number_format:
                cell.number_format = copy.copy(column_properties.number_format)
        # If column_properties is None or has no style, apply from row_dimensions if available
        if row_properties:
            if row_properties.fill:
                cell.fill = copy.copy(row_properties.fill)
            if row_properties.font:
                cell.font = copy.copy(row_properties.font)
            if row_properties.alignment:
                cell.alignment = copy.copy(row_properties.alignment)
            if row_properties.number_format:
                cell.number_format = copy.copy(row_properties.number_format)
    
def integrate_template_with_csv(template_path, csv_path, output_path):
    # Open template file
    template_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_path)
    template_ws = template_wb.active

    # Open CSV file
    with open(csv_path, newline='') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        csv_data = list(csvreader)
    
    # Fill template with CSV data
    for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(csv_data, start=1):
        for col_idx, cell_value in enumerate(row_data, start=1):
            if not cell_value:
                continue
            
            template_cell = template_ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx)
            if not isinstance(template_cell, openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
                target_cell = template_ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx)
                # Apply style from template
                apply_style_if_empty(template_ws, target_cell)
                target_cell.value = cell_value 
    
    # Save as a new file
    template_wb.save(output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_path = sys.argv[1]
    csv_path = sys.argv[2]
    template_path = sys.argv[3]

    integrate_template_with_csv(template_path, csv_path, output_path)

print(f"Data has been successfully integrated and saved as '{output_path}' file.")


Why can't you just select A1:C1000 in template file, and fill them with yellow? then you won't even need to write def apply_style_if_empty(worksheet, cell). it is a great function but I find it scary....

My program's users intend to use empty columns in the template.

I thought the point of using template.xlsx is to put all the formatting, colouring in template excel file, and then python is responsible for only populating numbers. You can make the formatted range large enough to accommodate all the data. e.g A1:C10000.  that is, anything other than entire column or entire row would work.

The Fill colour is a continuation of Column A with the number of columns it applies to specified by a range value.
E.g.
In your example where Columns A-C are filled then 
worksheet.column_dimensions only has Column A as the fill column 
So only worksheet.column_dimensions['A'] is valid 
and the range the Fill covers is worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].range which would return 'A:C' to signify that the Fill covers those columns

I still think it is much easier if people just select 10 rows, 10 columns and fill them with colour...

I changed to the program below.
In the template file, if the cell is None, the style of column_dimensions is imported from the template file.
In addition, if the header is applied with a style at once, we have applied both min and max values.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl
import csv
import sys
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
from copy import copy

def analyze_column_dimensions(ws):
    column_info = {}
    for col_letter, col_dim in ws.column_dimensions.items():
        info = {
            'range': (col_dim.min, col_dim.max),
            'width': col_dim.width,
            'hidden': col_dim.hidden,
            'custom_width': col_dim.customWidth,
            'style': {},
        }
        
        # Get style information from column properties
        column_properties = ws.column_dimensions.get(col_letter, None)
        if column_properties:
            info['style'] = {
                'fill': getattr(column_properties, 'fill', None),
                'font': getattr(column_properties, 'font', None),
                'alignment': getattr(column_properties, 'alignment', None),
                'border': getattr(column_properties, 'border', None),
            }
            # Find number format
            info['number_format'] = getattr(column_properties, 'number_format', 'General')

        for i in range(col_dim.min, col_dim.max + 1):
            column_info[get_column_letter(i)] = info
    
    return column_info

def apply_column_style(cell, style_info):
    if 'number_format' in style_info:
        cell.number_format = style_info['number_format']
    if style_info['style'].get('fill'):
        cell.fill = copy(style_info['style']['fill'])
    if style_info['style'].get('font'):
        cell.font = copy(style_info['style']['font'])
    if style_info['style'].get('alignment'):
        cell.alignment = copy(style_info['style']['alignment'])
    if style_info['style'].get('border'):
        cell.border = copy(style_info['style']['border'])

def is_column_empty(ws, col_letter):
    for cell in ws[col_letter]:
        if cell.value is not None:
            return False
    return True

def convert_to_number(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

def main(template_path, csv_path, output_path):
    # Open template file
    template_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_path)
    template_ws = template_wb.active

    # Analyze and store column information
    column_info = analyze_column_dimensions(template_ws)

    # Read CSV file
    csv_data = []
    with open(csv_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csv_reader:
            csv_data.append(row)

    # Apply CSV data and styles
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(csv_data, 1):
        for col_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
            col_letter = get_column_letter(col_idx)
            target_cell = template_ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx)
            
            # Check if the column is completely empty
            if target_cell.value is None:
                # If the column is empty, insert value and apply style
                converted_value = convert_to_number(value)
                cell = template_ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=converted_value)
                if col_letter in column_info:
                    apply_column_style(cell, column_info[col_letter])
            else:
                # If the column is not empty, update the existing cell value
                converted_value = convert_to_number(value)
                template_ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx).value = converted_value

    # Save the result
    template_wb.save(output_path)
    print(f"Processing is complete. Please check the '{output_path}' file.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print(f"Usage: python {sys.argv[0]} output_path csv_path template_path")
    else:
        output_path = sys.argv[1]
        csv_path = sys.argv[2]
        template_path = sys.argv[3]
        main(template_path, csv_path, output_path)


Thank you for moken's response.
But I did it as you told me, but there is an error as shown below.
import openpyxl
template_path = 'template.xlsx'
template_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_path)
worksheet = template_wb.active
worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].range

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ColumnDimension' object has no attribute 'range'

